# Send JWT from Client to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to use JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2 , 
I send Token from body and header in Postman, but received 401 Error,

code for create token:

```
var signature = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test API For JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2"));
var header = new SigningCredentials(signature, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var payload = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Username)

} , signingCredentials:header);

var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(payload);

return token;
```

startup.cs configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test API For JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2"))
            };
        });

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .Build();
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats your startup.cs configuration?

Comment: @wandos question updated

Comment: you set `ValidateIssuer = true` but not set `ValidIssuer`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if your request contains the `authorization` header with the value of `Bearer access_token`:

```
Authentication: Bearer KJVG32532UVBU78V...
```